# Derived column expression with -1

Tags: sql, ssis, derived-column

I am trying to figure out what a developer did when he setup a derived column in a SSIS package, He is looking up customer ID to insert to a table and has set the Expression value to "-1"

Why -1?

Comment: Presumably -1 refers to the "unknown customer" if the lookup doesn't find a matching customer record

Comment: if you change the connection type in execute sql task the parameter mappings is changed sometimes and the datatype is changed to -1. I am not aware this happening with derived column task but you can check once the actual package. The version change and other small changes can impact the package . The expression might be something else and not -1.